# Rust Deduped Cow HashSet

Tags: performance, rust, binaryfiles

Wanting to store a large number of byte arrays and aim to do this with a `AHashMap<Vec<u8>>` and using Cow borrow from it and only write when needed, this should also cause it to be deduplicated. However my attempts so far have been futile:

```rs
#![feature(hash_set_entry)]

use std::borrow::{Borrow, Cow, ToOwned};
use std::hash::Hash;

use ahash::AHashSet;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct CipherText<'a> {
    ciphertext: Cow<'a, Vec<u8>>,
    ciphers: Vec<Cipher<'a>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Cipher<'a> {
    cipher_id: Cow<'a, Vec<u8>>,
    keys: Vec<Cow<'a, Vec<u8>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut string_table: AHashSet<Vec<u8>> = vec![
        "Hello World!".as_bytes().to_vec(),
        "atbash".as_bytes().to_vec(),
        "caesar_decrypt".as_bytes().to_vec(),
        "5".as_bytes().to_vec(),
    ]
    .into_iter()
    .collect();

    let mut ciphertexts: Vec<CipherText> = vec![
        CipherText {
            ciphertext: Cow::Borrowed(
                string_table
                    .get(&"Hello World!".as_bytes().to_vec())
                    .unwrap(),
            ),
            ciphers: vec![Cipher {
                cipher_id: Cow::Borrowed(string_table.get(&"atbash".as_bytes().to_vec()).unwrap()),
                keys: vec![],
            }],
        },
        CipherText {
            ciphertext: Cow::Borrowed(
                string_table
                    .get(&"Hello World!".as_bytes().to_vec())
                    .unwrap(),
            ),
            ciphers: vec![Cipher {
                cipher_id: Cow::Borrowed(
                    string_table
                        .get(&"caesar_decrypt".as_bytes().to_vec())
                        .unwrap(),
                ),
                keys: vec![Cow::Borrowed(
                    string_table.get(&"5".as_bytes().to_vec()).unwrap(),
                )],
            }],
        },
    ];

    string_table.insert("TEST".as_bytes().to_vec());
    string_table.insert("TEST2".as_bytes().to_vec());

    ciphertexts[0].ciphertext = Cow::Borrowed(
        &string_table.get_or_insert_owned(&"Goodbye Cruel World...".as_bytes().to_vec()),
    );
}
```

Both of the TEST lines as well as the ciphertext[0] line error as follows

```rust
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `string_table` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:61:5
   |
33 |                 string_table
   |                 ------------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
61 |     string_table.insert("TEST".as_bytes().to_vec());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
64 |     ciphertexts[0].ciphertext = Cow::Borrowed(
   |     ----------- immutable borrow later used here
```

My aim is for all the byte arrays to only be references and then clone, add to the string_table and reference that if I change it. This data will be stored in a custom binary format and this is the start of the process for writing the serialiser and deserialiser. Hope this all makes sense!

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you have errors or the output just isn't what you expected?

Comment: @PeterHall edited it

Comment: Just move the two `string_table.insert` lines up to before the `let mut ciphertexts..`

Comment: `ciphertexts` borrows data from `string_table` and you trying to mutate `string_table` while `ciphertexts` is still in scope.

Comment: @PeterHall The string table is there as a more efficient representation for when strings are duplicated. I want the ciphertext vec to contain references to that string_table. When I change a value in the ciphertext vec if it exists in the string table i want to point to that else I want to create it in the string table and point to that. This would be done with Cow to make it more efficient. Sorry if it was poorly explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mutate `string_table` while a `CipherText` holds a reference to it. This is simply one of Rust's core invariants. So you cannot use `Cow`. The typical ways around it are generally either:

1. **Use indexes/keys** to reference the other structure, which unfortunately I can't see a good way to do that in this scenario.
2. **Use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html)s** so that the ciphertexts and the table *share* ownership of the bytes. This does mean that the ciphertexts can stand on their own, but you can always use the table as a broker to dedup elements before using them with judicious use of `get_or_insert`.

   ```
   #![feature(hash_set_entry)]

   use std::rc::Rc;
   use ahash::AHashSet;

   #[derive(Debug)]
   struct CipherText {
       ciphertext: Rc<Vec<u8>>,
       ciphers: Vec<Cipher>,
   }

   #[derive(Debug)]
   struct Cipher {
       cipher_id: Rc<Vec<u8>>,
       keys: Vec<Rc<Vec<u8>>>,
   }

   fn main() {
       let mut string_table: AHashSet<Rc<Vec<u8>>> = vec![
           Rc::new("Hello World!".as_bytes().to_vec()),
           Rc::new("atbash".as_bytes().to_vec()),
           Rc::new("caesar_decrypt".as_bytes().to_vec()),
           Rc::new("5".as_bytes().to_vec()),
       ]
       .into_iter()
       .collect();

       let mut ciphertexts: Vec<CipherText> = vec![
           CipherText {
               ciphertext: string_table
                   .get_or_insert(Rc::new("Hello World!".as_bytes().to_vec()))
                   .clone(),
               ciphers: vec![Cipher {
                   cipher_id: string_table
                       .get_or_insert(Rc::new("atbash".as_bytes().to_vec()))
                       .clone(),
                   keys: vec![],
               }],
           },
           CipherText {
               ciphertext: string_table
                   .get_or_insert(Rc::new("Hello World!".as_bytes().to_vec()))
                   .clone(),
               ciphers: vec![Cipher {
                   cipher_id: string_table
                       .get_or_insert(Rc::new("caesar_decrypt".as_bytes().to_vec()))
                       .clone(),
                   keys: vec![string_table
                       .get_or_insert(Rc::new("5".as_bytes().to_vec()))
                       .clone()],
               }],
           },
       ];

       string_table.insert(Rc::new("TEST".as_bytes().to_vec()));
       string_table.insert(Rc::new("TEST2".as_bytes().to_vec()));

       ciphertexts[0].ciphertext = string_table
           .get_or_insert(Rc::new("Goodbye Cruel World...".as_bytes().to_vec()))
           .clone();
   }
   ```

   This will have the same effect as `Cow`, the elements owned by the `Rc`s are immutable so a new element must be made to make changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response it has helped alot! Just wondering if/how it would be possible to remove items from string_table if they aren't being referenced?

Comment: You can tell that an `Rc` isn't used elsewhere if its [`strong_count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.strong_count) is `1`.